# Magento : Logging Broken

Tags: reports, ssl, log, exception, logging

**Debugging an SSL issue**, my host technician did something that disabled  logging on the site. He doesn't know what he did, and we can't get it working again. I've done the following:

- disable/enable logging
- change file/folder permissions to very open
- issuing Mage::log("error");
- Mage::log("error", null, "cust.log" true);

No luck.

Almost nothing logs in **/var/log**. Some things randomly shows up in `system.log`, but nothing will log to any other file, and no custom log files are created.

**Mage::log doesn't work throughout the site**. Also exceptions don't write to `var/report` and the **Sphinx search log** doesn't write to `var/sphinx`. Magento's exception screen appears showing file name, but the file doesn't appear in the reports directory.

Comment: which magento version you are using?

Comment: Using 1.9.0.1 updated through SUPEE-6788.

Comment: Have you turned on error handling via index.php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an Nginx security issue that the web host could never resolve. We eventually solved it by deploying to a different server.

Comment: what nginx security issue you talking about???

Comment: We could not determine the source of the error in the Apache log: sh: line 0: kill: (31174) - No such process